# Zxing barcode camera options

Tags: android, camera, barcode, zxing

I want to integrate the zing barcode scanner to my android application. so i used  zing integrator as follows

```
public Button.OnClickListener mScan = new Button.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent intent = new Intent("com.google.zxing.client.android.SCAN");
        intent.setPackage("com.google.zxing.client.android");
        intent.putExtra("SCAN_MODE", "QR_CODE_MODE");
        startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
    }};public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {
    if (requestCode == 0) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            String contents = intent.getStringExtra("SCAN_RESULT");
            String format = intent.getStringExtra("SCAN_RESULT_FORMAT");
            // Handle successful scan
        } else if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {
            // Handle cancel
        }
    }
}
```

i would like to implement this application in android tablet (2.2 version) which contains two cameras.
when i start this function, this automatically starts performing scan with back camera(Main), but according to my application needs, i need to perform the barcode scanning using only front camera. is there option something like

```
intent.putExtra("SCAN_MODE", "QR_CODE_MODE","FRONT_CAMERA");
```

1. is this possible to enable front camera with help of this zingintegrator  function? if not, do i need to  implement the whole zing open source code, so will it be possible to perform the scanning with only front camera. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

No, there's no support for this, really. The APIs for requesting the front camera did not appear until Android 2.3 (I think?) and Barcode Scanner is on 1.5 right now, moving to 2.1 soon. `Camera.open()` opens the rear camera by default and will not select the front camera.

Barcode Scanner does have an option to reverse the camera image, since we're told that at least one tablet *only* has a front camera, and for anything to work you need to reverse the image.

I can tell you that the front camera on devices is much worse than the rear camera in general. its resolution and CCD responsiveness make it hard to scan this way.

Comment: Thanks Sean, But i really need to work only Front camera (my application requirement), i am using the tablet  "viewpad7"from viewsonic.

Comment: You'll have to write your own app then, and access the Camera using the new APIs. Once you have image data off that camera you can use the core library for actual scanning of course. It's just the Android bits you need to create from scratch.

Comment: Update. I have back-ported code from Barcode Scanner+ that will attempt to open a front camera on 2.3+ devices.