# unable to scan barcode with front camera

Tags: android, camera, barcode, zbar

We are using Zbar library scan code type 128 barcode, library works properly for back-end camera in android devices and also gives successful scan result. But when we used the same library for Front camera in android devices it gives garbage results for scan and sometime it does not scan at all.

Please provide some solution for this problem.

Comment: Can you indicate how you specified the front camera?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a many reasons behind that, the front camera has a very low MP, ans in many cases they can not be auto focused. This is why it can not scan bar codes properly.

You may refer:
[Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7901299/zxing-barcode-camera-options)

Answer (score 1):

As front camera is always low resolution. Therefore it might not be able to read the bar code properly.